# Cannot save new Rails 3 ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a webapp that allows users to create scavenger hunts.  Trouble is, I can't seem to convince Rails to save new hunts.  Here's my setup.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Model:

```
class Hunt < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 } ,
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

Controller:

```
class HuntController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @title = "All Hunts"
     @hunts = Hunt.order("name ASC")     
  end

  def show
    @hunt = Hunt.find(params[:id])
    @title = @hunt.name    
  end

  def new
    @hunt = Hunt.new
    @title = "New Hunt"  
  end

  def create
    @hunt = Hunt.new(params[:hunt]) #fixed type (used to be this: Hunt.new(params[:id]) )
    if @hunt.save
      flash[:success] = "Hunt created!"
      redirect_to index
    else
      @title = "New Hunt"
      render 'new'

    end

    ...

end
```

View

```
    <h1>Sign up</h1>

    <%= form_for(@hunt) do |f| %>

        <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :name %><br />
         <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Routes

```
MyChi::Application.routes.draw do


  get "hunts/index"
  get "hunts/new"
  get "hunts/create"  
  get "hunts/show"
  get "hunts/list"  
  get "hunts/edit"
  get "hunts/delete"

  match '/hunts', :to => 'hunts#index'

  resource :hunts

  .....

  root :to => "pages#home"

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

EDIT: I should mention that when a new hunt is added, the app redirects the user to Index, but there's no flash notification of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your create action, change Hunt.new(params[:id]) to Hunt.new(params[:hunt])

Comment: Didn't see that type.  Thanks.  Unfortunately, that's not the troublemaker.  I fixed the typo, but still have the problem.

Comment: your controller class should be plural "HuntsController", can you check the logs and see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: So I change "HuntController" to "HuntsController", updated the routes files and restarted the server.  Unfortunately, it hasn't changed the behavior of my app. Any other ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: In your routes do you have resources :hunts

Comment: Yes. I posted the relevant bits of my routes file.

Comment: There is your problem.  get "hunts/create" . It is a post request. Erase everything above resource :hunts and also change that line to resources :hunts (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

Comment: Kyle--thank you!  Fixed the routes file and the problem's gone.  You are awesome.  Thank you so much for your help.  And I appreciate the link too.  Looks like I've got some reading to do!